# Windows 10 Non paged Pool Memory Usage

Tags: windows-10, memory

Using Poolmon.exe I saw something really bizzare. One of the tag is using 23GB of memory, but my PC only has 16G of memory in total. How is that possible? From the task manager I can see the nonpaged pool usage is at 4.5GB which is definitely abnormal.

[image: 23GB of nonpaged memory usage in a 16GB memory PC]

Comment: any update? Have you found the driver/tool with the help of WPR/WPA? Or do you need more help?

Comment: Think I fixed it by updating my network driver, although the basic RAM usage is still quite high IMO, often using up to 4~5G when I am just browsing websites etc

Comment: ok, if the answer helped, mark it as answer and create a new question and post RAMMap pictures when the usage is high

Answer (score 0):

Most usage comes from the tag `Nbt8` (`NetBT address list`) which belongs to the Windows driver`netbt.sys`.

To trace this, you have to use Event Tracing for Windows. Download this [WPRP profile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/onhmodh96sc7ewr/PoolTagLeak_Nbt8.wprp?dl=0), open a cmd.exe as admin and run this command to trace 3 minutes of pool usage grow:

```
wpr.exe -start "fullPath\PoolTagLeak_Nbt8.wprp" && timeout 500 && wpr.exe -stop result.etl
```

Install now the [Windows Performance Toolkit, part of the Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), Open the ETL with WPA.exe, add the Pool graphs to the analysis pane.

Put the pooltag column at first place and add the stack column. Now [load the symbols](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) inside WPA.exe and expand the stack of the tag that you saw in poolmon.

[image]

Now find other 3rd party drivers which you can see in the stack. Here the `Thre` tag (Thread) is used by AVKCl.exe from G-Data. Look for driver/program updates to fix it. Maybe other 3rd party tools trigger the netbt.sys usage.